# Output plugins used by protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Protractor 2.0.0. introduces this neat idea of [extending protractor with plugins](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.0.0/docs/plugins.md) offering several built-in plugins, like `ngHint`, `console` or `timeline`.

Currently, I'm trying to make the `timeline` plugin work and I'd like to see a more verbose output on the console in order to debug the problem.

Is it possible to see on the console what plugins are loaded by `protractor`?

FYI, created an issue: [Protractor to report loaded plugins](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1961).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1961) (currently merged to the development `protractor` - master branch) closing the [Protractor to report loaded plugins](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/2219) issue.

Now, if you run protractor with [`--troubleshoot` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636811/protractor-troubleshooting), you'll get the list of loaded plugins:

```
DEBUG - Running with --troubleshoot
DEBUG - Protractor version: 2.1.0
DEBUG - Your base url for tests is http://127.0.0.1:9001
...
DEBUG - Plugin "/path/to/node_modules/protractor/plugins/console/index.js" loaded.
DEBUG - Plugin "/path/to/node_modules/protractor/plugins/timeline/index.js" loaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I did not find something in the code of the [plugins.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/plugins.js). If I run Protractor tests with enabled plugins, on the console I only see the result output of a plugins hook method. This assumes that the plugin has been loaded correctly.

I think this is a missing feature. I look forward on your (or someones) contribution for [Issue 1961](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1961).