# Troubleshoot option not printing plugin for protractor

Tags: plugins, protractor

I am trying to find out if my plugin is being loaded for my protractor tests. The plugin is `protractor-istanbul-plugin` but when I enter `protractor myConf.js --troubleshoot` on the command line it does not print out the data that it is said to from the accepted answer from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214140/output-plugins-used-by-protractor) Am I missing something in my code maybe? I can't find anything that details what I should be doing other than what I already am.

Comment: Could it be that you don't have any plugins loaded leading to not having this information printed on the console? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe

My conf file with my plugin loaded:

exports.config = {

    plugins: [{
path: 'C:/Users/user/product/project/node_modules/protractor-istanbul-plugin/index.js',
        logAssertions: true,
        failAssertions: true
    }]
...
It runs, I was having issues with it not finding the path for the plugin before but it's fine now.

Comment: @alecxe I know I said that it runs, but what I'm saying is that the tests run but it still does not print out the troubleshoot information. Sorry if I was a little confusing.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I can reproduce that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `--troubleshoot` flag is being broken since version 3.2.1 (experimentally determined).

I've created an issue in Protractor issue tracker to confirm if this is a bug:

- [Is troubleshoot flag still working?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3522)

This is now fixed in "trunk" and will be released in the next version (4.0.5).

Comment: So is my plugin actually being loaded then? Is there any other way I can check if it is?

Comment: @Jooba0352 the issue is already fixed (yeah, that was very quick). You can try installing Protractor from github directly and use the `troubleshoot` flag. Thanks.