# Protractor webdriver on Windows won't execute any test but says all are passing

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

My colleague has a computer that runs Windows 7. For whatever reason after an update to all of the NPM modules it has been executing the tests immediately without waiting for the default navigation to execute. All of the tests show as passing, but no test is being executed.

Also, if I edit the protractor.js file directly to get the browser URL (using browser.getCurrentUrl().then()) it doesn't execute the promises. In other places where promises should work they don't. As if the promise library doesn't exist or isn't resolving properly for protractor.

Protractor isn't even waiting for the browser to navigate to the default URL of 'data:text/html,'.

A different Windows 7 machine works fine, and a gulp-protractor task runs the test suite as expected.

- Protractor: 3.2.2
- NodeJS: 5.10.1 (latest stable)

We've also installed protractor globally, as someone in our department suggested although I had reservations about this. It didn't solve the issue.

I've deleted the node_modules directory both globally and locally to the project, reinstalled everything, re-cloned the project, and re-ran the entire setup again.

**Command being executed:**

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js spec/conf/protractor.e2eTests.js --suite smoke
```

A recent change for our Jenkins server was to include this command to install the webdriver for gulp-webdriver as well as protractor's standard webdriver:

```
"myScript": "npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ && node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update && node ./node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone"
```

The npm install has several warnings due to packages using old dependency versions, but no fatal errors.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. At this point we're thinking of re-imaging the machine to fix the problem.

Comment: Could you show what do you have inside the protractor config? Also, what is the output on the console if you start protractor in ["troubleshoot" mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636811/protractor-troubleshooting)? Thanks.